Property select-package is not allowed in melos.yaml
Problem
I found this issue when working on the step running test cases in specific packages on the melos starter project in this repo melos_demo for Manage multi-package Flutter projects. My flutter version is Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.3).
Expected results
It should not display any warning in melos.yaml.


We should change melos.yaml based on this post https://invertase.io/blog/announcing-melos-v3-new-features-improvements-and-breaking-changes

Changes in package filters: The select-package option for scripts has been renamed to packageFilters, and filter names are now camel-cased instead of kebab-cased.


Ref:
https://github.com/SAGARSURI/melos_demo/pull/2
